# Can't upload a file to nginx server with fetch

Tags: php, laravel, http, nginx

I have an application written with Laravel where I upload and serve some files. It worked fine until I tried to upload a file that is 124MB in size. Fetch request raises:

**ERR_QUIC_PROTOCOL_ERROR.QUIC_IETF_GQUIC_ERROR_MISSING**

And when I disable Experimental QUIC protocol on chrome://flags than the fetch request fails   with

**TypeError: Failed to fetch**

There is nothing on the error.log and according to the access.log the POST request doesn't make it to the server.

The server is **nginx version: nginx/1.18.0** (Ubuntu)

The relevant php settings are below. The same settings are configured for my local Xampp configuration and upload works fine on local.

```
max_execution_time=300
upload_max_filesize = 0
post_max_size = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

NGINX has a max POST size limit. Change it to `client_max_body_size 256M;` or what ever you need in a `server` or `location` config:

```
location /uploads {
   ...
   client_max_body_size 256M;
}
```

Don't forget to restart the service after the modification.

Comment: Thanks but I forgot the mention that I already set it to 0. Anyway, nginx wasn't the problem, Cloudflare was.

Comment: Ok! Glad you fixed it. Effectively, we cannot guess that you already set it neither guess that you had Cloudflare in front too.

Answer (score 1):

Finally after trying for hours fetch request returned a response with the cause of the error. The culprit turned out to be Cloudflare. Cloudflare allows up to 100MB of uploads in the free plan. I disabled proxy for the subdomain, installed certbot for ssl and everything is working now.